# iphone NStimer start in 2 seconds

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I am trying to have a block of code run 2 seconds after I 'start' it.

I think the NSTimer can do this but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following will do what you need:

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2 
                                   target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(handleTimer:) 
                                   userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:NO];
```

Then the delegate function:

```
-(void)handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer 
{       
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 19):

NSTimer can be used, but another option is to use [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)  It's basically like a method call (message send) that happens later.

This example will send a doStuff: message after a delay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:self afterDelay:2];
```

which causes this method to get invoked 2.0 seconds later:

```
-(void)doStuff:(id)sender 
{
    /// do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use some handy code :

NSObject+PerformBlock.h

```
@interface NSObject (PerformBlock)

- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block repeatCount:(NSUInteger)repeatCount timeInteval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval;

@end
```

NSObject+PerformBlock.m

```
@interface NSObject (PerformBlockHidden)

- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block;

@end

@implementation NSObject (PerformBlock)

- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block {
    block();
}

- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait {
    [self performSelector:@selector(performBlock:) onThread:nil withObject:[[block copy] autorelease] waitUntilDone:wait];
}

- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {
    [self performSelector:@selector(performBlock:) withObject:[[block copy] autorelease] afterDelay:delay];
}

- (void)performBlock:(void(^)(void))block repeatCount:(NSUInteger)repeatCount timeInteval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval {
    for (NSInteger repetition = 0; repetition < repeatCount; repetition++)
        [self performBlock:block afterDelay:(repetition*timeInterval)];
}

@end
```

Then just import NSObject+PerformBlock.h and call :

```
[myObject performBlock:^{
    // Code you want to perform after 2secs
} afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: I haven't used this, but I really like the concept of using blocks like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the `NSTimeInterval` to 2.0 seconds and it should fire after that amount of time. What are you seeing? What is the code you are using to invoke the timer?