# iPhone Accelerometer > csv > email

Tags: iphone, csv, email, accelerometer

I'm trying to collect data for a machine learning project I'm working on.  What I'd like to do is collect accelerometer data from an iPhone, save it to a csv and email it to myself.  My app currently is able to acquire data from the accelerometer, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.  First of all, I'd like to acquire data for a preset amount of time (after playing a sound to the user) which I don't really know how to do, and I can't find good documentation for.  Also, I'd like to save that to a csv, which there is some documentation on (specifically using the NSString writeToFile method).  Any recommendations/ ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: For the CSV part, see these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159576/how-to-export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-iphone-sdk-3-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512883/how-to-convert-data-to-csv-or-html-format

Answer (score 1):

Take it one step at a time.

You can set an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) to get a callback at some point in the future and at the callback you can stop your data acquisition.

***EDIT:*** 
You can also use a [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) to get a callback after a time delay to stop data acquisition.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784809/iphone-nstimer-start-in-2-seconds) has answers with example code for both methods.