# How Can I Start And Stop NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I develop Stop Watch Application. 
In my application, there are Two UIButtons , `StartBtn` and `StopBtn`, And also I use `NSTimer`.

Now, i want to start `NSTimer` when user click on `StartBtn` and also stop when your click on `StopBtn`.

I know that `NSTimer` is stopped by `[MyTimerName invalidate];` method but I don't know how to start `NSTimer` again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone NStimer start in 2 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784809/iphone-nstimer-start-in-2-seconds)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The `NSTimer` class is a bit awkward to use; rather than separating the creation/destruction from the start/stop, it's all rolled together.  In other words the timer starts as soon as it's created and stops as soon as it's destroyed.

You therefore need to use the *existence* of the `NSTimer` object as a flag to indicate if it's running; something like this:

```
// Private Methods
@interface MyClass ()
{
    NSTimer *_timer;
}
- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    if (!_timer) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender {
    if ([_timer isValid]) {
        [_timer invalidate];
    }
    _timer = nil;
}

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"ping");
}
```

Comment: @AmitJarsaniya Yes you can; it creates a new `NSTimer` object when you start it and destroys it when you stop it.

Comment: One correction:
    selector:@selector(_timerFired)
should be
    selector:@selector(_timerFired:). Note the final colon after the method name (as its part of the method name in ObjC).

Comment: @CodyA.Ray Nope; note the method is called `- (void)_timerFired` and not `- (void)_timerFired:(id)sender`.

Comment: Oh, right. I think I also had to make _timerFired accept (NSTimer *)timer for this to work. Otherwise I got an unrecognized selector issue.

Comment: @CodyA.Ray Yes, that is true, as documented in the `NSTimer` class reference.

Comment: @trajanfoe: I think you should release the timer in `stopTimer:` because you retain it in `startTimer:`. The doc says `The NSRunLoop object removes and releases the timer`, but NSRunLoop must have retained it too.

Comment: @Martin Well spotted; that `retain` is an error I believe, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 14):

You could always use fire to start a NStimer again

```
  [timer fire];
```

To stop it:

```
  [timer invalidate];
  //remember to set timer to nil after calling invalidate;
  timer = nil;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can start the timer through

```
#define kRefreshTimeInSeconds 1
 NSTimer *myTimerName;
 .
 .
 myTimerName = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: kRefreshTimeInSeconds 
                                   target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(handleTimer:) 
                                   userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];
```

Then the delegate function:

```
-(void)handleTimer: (id) sender 
{       
   //Update Values in Label here
}
```

And to stop Timer

```
-(void)stopTimer: (id) sender 
{       
   if(myTimerName)
   {
       [myTimerName invalidate];
        myTimerName = nil;
   }
}
```