# I can not stop Timer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios10

I'm creating timer and loop like this.

```
private var iteration:Int = 0
private var syncTimer:Timer? = Timer()

//MARK: - Singleton
static let synchronizationInstance:DeviceSynchronization = DeviceSynchronization()
private init(){ 
}

public func synchronizeAllDevices(){         
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.syncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(DeviceSynchronization.synchronizeDevices), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.syncTimer?.fire()
        }
    }
}

@objc private func synchronizeDevices(){
    if iteration >= 7 {
        syncTimer?.invalidate()
        syncTimer = nil
        iteration = 0
    } else {
        devicesList![iteration].synchroniseState()
        iteration += 1
    }
}
```

When it reaches seven reps `syncTimer?.invalidate()` and `syncTimer = nil` should stop `syncTimer` but nothing happens. Timer still works. I don't know here is bug.

Comment: You might be called the `synchronizeAllDevices ` again somewhere in your code, `.invalidate()` should work fine

Comment: As far as I tested your code shown above (I needed to move an unbalanced closing brace), your code worked as expected. As Tj3n suggested, you have some faults in somewhere you are hiding.

Comment: I'm not sure about where is the implemention of the class _DeviceSynchronization_, but after the first glance that it seems the `#selector(DeviceSynchronization.synchronizeDevices)` is supposed to be this: `#selector(DeviceSynchronization.synchronizationInstance.synchronizeDevices)` instead; but it is not clear whether this snippet from/in the actual _DeviceSynchronization_ class or not.

Comment: I change #selector(DeviceSynchronization.synchronizationInstance.synchronizeDevices) to #selector(DeviceSynchronization.synchronizationInstance.synchronizeDevices) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @WujoFefer, you may need to post the completed implementation to see the whole picture, because in my test class your code works flawlessly and the timer stops after the 7th iteration; but in my test class all of your code (as is) inside the `DeviceSynchronization` class's implementation; but it is not clear at all how that class looks on your screen.

Comment: Show where you call `synchronizeAllDevices`.

Comment: just try  syncTimer!.invalidate()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Start And Stop NSTimer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052914/how-can-i-start-and-stop-nstimer)

Answer (score 0):

My sync code start when app connect to server In Stream.Event.openCompleted.

```
internal func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {

    switch eventCode {
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        log.info("The open has completed successfully.")
        reconnectCount = 0
        syncAllDevices.synchronizeAllDevices()
        break
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        log.info("The stream can accept bytes for writing.")
        break
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        receveData()
        break
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        log.info("An error has occurred on the stream.")
        break
        reconnect()
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        log.info("The end of the stream has been reached.")
        break
    default:
        log.info(„Unknown error”)
        break
    }
}
```

After 2 seconds I'm trying to sync all devices (objects) in list. 
I found that this event is triggered two times and I don't know why but this created 2 timers in singleton...

Solved!
My problem was when Stream.Event.openCompleted triggered two times thats why my synchronization class creates two timers... 
I solved the problem by creating a true/false variable "isSyncIsInProgress".